# HTML table, when i ctrl+click, the border of the cell appears?

Tags: javascript, html

I have put an onclick listener on the row element n a table, but when i do click on a row (whilst pressing ctrl), a border appears around the cell i clicked on.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: That depends on the html, the css and the JavaScript you're using. If you can post those (or a live demo to reproduce your problem on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)) it'd help us to help you.

Answer (score 12):

I think you're running into something that Firefox does by default for tables.

This snippet that I found somewhere works for me:

```
$('table').mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that @casablanca's solution will fix the problem of the blue border appearing. But it will also stop you from selecting the table contents which you might want. If you instead make it a selective return of `false` (or call `preventDefault()`) only when the CTRL key is pressed, you should hopefully have something that does what you need.

Answer (score 9):

I found this question looking for the solution myself.  I thought I'd share what I found elsewhere that seems to do the trick.  Note - this is a firefox issue.

Solution is to add "-moz-user-select: none;" for table elements that you want to disable this behavior.

found at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/763547

Answer (score 5):

This is a browser feature that allows users to easily select multiple cells/rows of a table -- you can't specifically disable this, but you can disable selections altogether by trapping `onmousedown` and returning `false` in the handler.

Comment: Problem is i need to be able to select the whole row for the work i am doing, so i presume this wouldn't work?

Comment: @Tom: @no.good.at.coding's solution might work better -- you can check for the Ctrl key before returning false.